# Can I access information from one associated AR object in another when both are unsaved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I open a Rails (2.3.8) script console and try this:

```
a = Account.new(:first_name) = 'foo'
i = a.invoices.build
p i.account.first_name
```

Account.rb is a model object and contains:
  has_many :invoices

and Invoice.rb is a model as well containing:
  belongs_to :account, :validate => true

In console line 3 above, i.account is nil. I realize that i.account would not be nil if account had been saved, but I do not wish to save an account unless I can create a valid invoice for the account. And, just for kicks, the invoice validation depends on some properties of the unsaved account.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Best,
Will

Answer (score 0):

I typically do this with transactions.  With rails transactions you can perform db interactions and roll them back at any time if something fails to validate. For example:
in your model:

```
def save_and_create_invoice
  Account.transaction do
     #first let's save the account, this will give us an account_id to work with
     return false unless self.save
     invoice = self.invoices.build
     #setup your invoice here and then save it
     if invoice.save
         #nothing wrong? return true so we know it was ok
         return true
     else
         #add the errors so we know what happened
         invoice.errors.full_messages.each{|err| errors.add_to_base(err)}
         #rollback the db transaction so the account isn't saved
         raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
         #return false so we know it failed
         return false
     end
  end
end
```

And in your controller you would call it like so:

```
def create
 @account = Account.new(params[:account])
 respond_to do |format|
  if @account.save_and_create_invoice
     format.html
  else
     format.html {render :action => "new"}
  end
 end
end
```

Note that I didn't run this code to test it, just whipped it out real quick to show an example.